# Linq возвращает IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .netcore2.0, entity-framework-core

Всем сново привет, мой вопрос так и не решился, опишу заново:
Проблема в том, что вместо привычного отложенного запроса как в старом добром .net, EF выгружает все в память и там сортирует при использовании where из system.linq. Т.е. возвращает IEnumerable вместо IQueryable. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне интересно почему компилятор не видит тип IQueryable ведь dbset как раз его реализует. Ладно если в бд будет 10 записей, а если 10 миллионов?

Net core 2.0
Создал отдельный проект библиотеки классов